# Retrieve multiple checkbox and display other related information from database in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I got this list of checkboxes that print out from database. I am able to retrieve data from database if user makes multiple checkbox and display it in table, but i cannot retrieved other information from database and display it in the same table.

This is my code:

```
<table border='1'>

<tr>
<th>TITLE</th>
<th>PERCENTAGE RESULT</th>
</tr>

<?php 

if(isset ($_POST["submit1"]))
{
    $selectedcheckbox = $_POST["selectedcheck"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM compareresult where subject=$selectedcheckbox";
   $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query,MYSQL_ASSOC)){

      $result=$data['result'];
    }

    foreach($selectedcheckbox as $title)
    {

       echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$title."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$result."</td>";
    }           
        echo "</tr>";

}
?>
```

I want to display result after user select multiple checkbox, so I wrote:

```
 echo $result in table
```

so that the result can be displayed in table beside the selected title, but I am getting an error:

> Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sam\c.php on line 31 Error 3 :Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Comment: I can see already you have a close statement to much (a bracket) And can you put down what error you get, cause this way we ll shoot blanks at you. Also, what value returns the $selectedcheckbox? Is it just a digit as ID, or is it a name? I can also already tell you that it will return one statement, cause you dont loop your query. So your whole post array will be entered in the query so it cant find your query, thus probably the error

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. It's perhaps better you read a book about this topic and follow some tutorials instead. I also recommend you to consider using PDO oder Mysli instead of Mysql.

Comment: @Dorvalla.. $selectedcheckbox comes from other page.php that post the value of multiple selected checkbox.. it comes from this code..<input type="checkbox" name="selectedcheck[]" value="<?php echo $title?>" />

Comment: @Dorvalla this is the error... Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sam\c.php on line 31
Error 3 :Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not at the moment in the environment to test your problem, and I do this out of my head, but try something like the following.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $checkbox = isset($_POST['selectedcheck']) ? $_POST['selectedcheck'] : array();
    foreach($checkbox as $title){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM compareresult where subject='".$title."'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);  // <-- to avoid SQL injections, please change your method from mysql_query to mysqli_query (use the mysqli functions instead of mysql) 
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             $result=$data['result'];

             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>".$title."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$result."</td>";
             echo "</tr>
             }
        } 
   }
```

It checks first if your checkboxes are checked and if they are they put it in an array.
Then it runs the foreach statement, where it sets the checkbox value as title. It runs there if the query if it the title is in the database, if so, spit it out through the while loop. Rinse and repeat until done.

**edit**

I see you put your open tablerow statement in the foreach but close it outside. So either you want it all printed on one line or is it an error? If its on one line, make sure you open the table row BEFORE the while loop and end it AFTER, else it's like how i spit it out.

Comment: Good answer, but it's a good idea not to replicate SQL injection bugs in OP code. I'd fix it (since it is one line) or at least point it out somewhere in your description.

Comment: @halfer updated with a pointer towards the mysql / mysqli function. I agree with your statement, that pdo or mysqli are much safer.

Comment: I'd just use `$escapedTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($title)` for now, but yes, parameterisation would be better.